# SparkContext Initialization Error: Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am running spark using the following run command:

```
spark-submit --class "Pagecounts" --master local[*] target/scala-2.11/Pagecounts-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar <some_file_name>
```

But I am getting the following initialization error:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-    defaults.properties                                                                                             
16/10/01 18:26:09 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.0.0                                                                                                            
16/10/01 18:26:12 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library     for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable                              
16/10/01 18:26:13 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.                                                                                                      
java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-21ql.site: linux-21ql.site: unknown error
```

Can someone please help with this issue?

Comment: Check your `/etc/hosts` file. Looks like localhost isn't being resolved correctly. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378763/java-net-unknownhostexception-in-while-running-play-framework-activator)  deals with a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks...it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant local deploy this application like this because jar need spark environment to run spark application but here local[*] nothing so if you want to run application locally then simply set master local[*] in your SparkConf object like below

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]")
```

Or if you want to run like above spark-submit you should create local cluster as given here https://blog.knoldus.com/2015/04/14/setup-a-apache-spark-cluster-in-your-single-standalone-machine/

and deploy jar like above you mention just change master value with spark://IP:PORT